# Disabled screen lock - don't want to clear credentials

Tags: samsung-galaxy-note-3

I am using **Samsung Galaxy Note 3 N9005**. In order to use the university WiFi network I need to install an authority certificate (WiFi credential). To do so, the device made me installing a look screen (Pin or Password), any other lock screen choice is not available and grayed with a message "**Disabled by administrator, encryption policy or credential storage**"

I need to change/cancel the annoying pin lock screen, without needing to clear all credentials in order to keep using the university WiFi.

what can I do about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The certificate is stored in Credential Storage, which requires a pin/password to be set for use in encrypting/decrypting the certificate. The nature of the problem is documented [here on code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1052) and you can star the issue, so hopefully Google will address it in future.

Comment: link is broken...

Comment: Yea, that version of Android is no longer in Preview so it appears Google has taken down the bug tracker. The link did not provide any further insight into the issue, beyond stating it was due to Credential Storage being designed to requiring a pin/password any time 3rd party certificates were installed.

Answer (score 1):

Just go to setting / more networks / VPN 
and delete the VPN after that go to screen lock u will find activated.

Answer (score 0):

If your device is [root](/questions/tagged/root)ed, you can circumvent that by copying the CA file as *system* certificate. For that, the `/system` partition needs to be mounted read/write. Either use a "root explorer" (file manager with root support) to copy the file, copy it using a terminal emulator, or push it via ADB (requires the ADB daemon to run in root mode). With Android 4.0+:

```
# via ADB push:
adb push d123456.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/d123456.0

# via terminal emulator (after having copied the certificate to your device):
cp d123456.0 /system/etc/security/cacerts/d123456.0
```

After that, mount `/system` read-only again (or reboot the device), and you are done.

Of course you'd need to revert your previous user-certificate stuff to get rid of the lock-screen restrictions. The appropriate functionality can be found in *Settings → Security* under "Credentials", where you have to "clear user credentials".

Answer (score -1):

Those policies are imposed when you give an app permission to be a "device administrator". In order to remove the policies, go to **Settings → Security → Device administrators**, look for an item in the list associated with the app that imposed the policies, and uncheck it. Be aware that doing so may disable the application, or some of its functionality, and may delete associated data.

Comment: It is a wifi/vpn certificate and you cannot disable it,  removing it will prevent you from authenticating your next connection to the wifi/vpn. I only have android device manager in administrators list.